# Can "wondering" be using in the following way?

Tags: grammar

> After some pondering and wondering, she called Tom.

I think you should put something after wondering. Example: "After some wondering about this..." But maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wondering what it would be like to be a cowboy, I bought a cowboy hat at the country clothing store.

I was wondering why came to class late every day. Then I found out that he commuted by bicycle, everyday, from 30 miles away.

There are a couple examples.

Comment: After she finished pondering and wondering whether she should continue in the relationship, she called Tom.

Answer (score 1):

> After some pondering and wondering, she called Tom.

When presented in a standalone manner like that, your sentence does leave me wondering what she was wondering about.

However, a sentence like that one could be just fine inside a paragraph that provided more context, such as:

> After their bitter argument last night, Kim didn't know if she would ever see Tom again. She should have listened to her mother's advice – never talk politics on the first date! Everything had been going so well. Was Tom ready to give it another chance? After some pondering and wondering, she picked up the phone.

or:

> Sitting in her real estate office, this customer didn't look trustworthy. He didn't look like a man ready to buy a home – not with his scruffy beard, his dirty coat, and his nervous demeanor. Did she really want to show him that old farmhouse outside of town? Maybe her associate, Tom, would be willing to take the 20-minute drive with them. Could it ever hurt to be too safe? After some pondering and wondering, she called Tom.